# How to log on an admin page without having access to anything?

Tags: admin, login, captcha, admin-login

**Some context is needed here** : I just started a placement at a place where they used Magento to create their website. I don't yet have access to the code of the site, so I'm trying to log as an admin using the admin panel. Login form asks for a captcha, which appears from time to time and the image won't load at anytime. I might have access to the code later but for the moment I'm stuck with nothing to do.
Is there a way to ignore that captcha so I can login ?

**EDIT** : captcha bugs are resolved now, but putting in the username/password that should be correct won't work (saying *You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled*)

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact whoever has administration access to the Magento admin so they can provide you with the access you need. If you were never given that then you are not going to be able to login. Or, if you have that and are now getting login failures, your account may be locked due to failures. Either way, the admin administrator should be able to resolve this.

Comment: Thank you a lot, he has been contacted and is resolving it apparently !